# HighCharts - When I download csv, can I switch data source to new one?

Tags: csv, highcharts

Current Data source:

```
xAxis: {
    categories: ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec']
},

series: [{
    data: [29.9, 71.5, 106.4, 129.2, 144.0, 176.0, 135.6, 148.5, 216.4, 194.1, 95.6, 54.4]
}]
```

Current CSV:

[image: Current CSV]

Demo:
http://jsfiddle.net/puff0211/2sonqy1r/

Desired CSV:

```
  "Date",    "RawData1", "RawData2", "RawData3"
  "2018-01-01",      1,  "RawData2", "RawData3" 
  "2018-01-02",      2,  "RawData2", "RawData3" 
  "2018-01-03",      3,  "RawData2", "RawData3" 
  "2018-01-04",      4,  "RawData2", "RawData3" 
  "2018-01-05",      5,  "RawData2", "RawData3"
```

Does anyone know to accomplish following conditions?

When I download csv, I need to switch csv data source to raw data. (like Desired CSV)

Thank you!

Comment: You will need to create your own function to transform `jan` to "2018-01-01"

Comment: @Core972  I thknk no need transform, it's different data source.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can return your own CSV if you overwrite the `getCSV` function:

```
(function(H) {
  H.Chart.prototype.getCSV = function() {
    // return your own csv here
    return `    "Date","RawData1", "RawData2", "RawData3"
    "2018-01-01", 1, "RawData2", "RawData3" 
    "2018-01-02", 2, "RawData2", "RawData3" 
    "2018-01-03", 3, "RawData2", "RawData3" 
    "2018-01-04", 4, "RawData2", "RawData3" 
    "2018-01-05", 5, "RawData2", "RawData3"`
  };
})(Highcharts);
```

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/kkulig/fvo2ytyy/

**Docs about extending Highcharts core:** https://www.highcharts.com/docs/extending-highcharts/extending-highcharts